# Hosting corporate applications on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpc

I am trying to move a corporate web application to EC2, and this application uses windows authentication. So I am wondering if I can use Amazon VPC to access the application on AWS EC2   using windows authentication from my existing corporate domain. 
Please advise Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EC2 Instances running Windows are just like any other Windows machine, even if they are running behind a VPC.

Things you need to consider might be:

- How to pass administration credentials to these machine? - Here you can set up an IAM Role for these instances that can read a private bucket on S3 that have these credentials. You can then pass the name of the bucket in the *User Data* field when you start these instances. See more details here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/role-usecase-ec2app.html
- How to have a secure network between your internal network and the servers in the VPC? You can attach an additional Elastic Network Interface (ENI) that is not available for public access on top of your public IP. This ENI allows you to create a *management network* with your corporate domain. See more details here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ElasticNetworkInterfaces.html

You might also want to take a look at [AWS Direct Connect](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/directconnect/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html)

If you have any other specific concerns, please update your question.